# NHibernate compare local date year and month with collections of dates

Tags: c#, lambda, nhibernate

What I would like to do is:

```
tradingObjectQueryOver.Where(
  Restrictions
    .On<OrderDealDto>(d => d.UnderlyingContractMaturity.Value.ToContractName())
    .IsInG(filter.ContractDates.ToContractName()));
```

where

```
public const string ContractNameFormat = "MMMyy";
public static string ToContractName(this LocalDate date)
{
    return date.ToString(ContractNameFormat, UsCulture).ToUpper();
}
```

and thus I cannot call d.UnderlyingContractMaturity.Value.ToContractName() as SQL knows nothing about c# methods like ToString. What is the easiest way  to fix this, ex TSQL dependant functions?

```
new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.String, "FORMAT(?1, 'yyyMM', 'us-US')");
```

but at the same time I do not want to kill performance, this is just minuscule part of the query and there are on the scale of 100k-10m elements in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a function on sql side

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_ToContractName] (@date DATE)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(5)
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN UPPER(REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),@date, 6), 6), ' ', ''))
END
```